# Expanding a Fusion Drive partition

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, core-storage

I created a partition on my Fusion Drive when I first purchased my iMac running Yosemite, and I would like to now resize that drive ("Data" in the screenshot below), but Disk Utility doesn't allow it (the "Partition" button is disabled).

[image: Partition button is disabled]

**diskutil list**

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
    0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
    1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
    2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            121.0 GB   disk0s2
    3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
    0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk1
    1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
    2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            2.7 TB     disk1s2
    3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.1 MB   disk1s3
    4:                  Apple_HFS Data                    326.8 GB   disk1s4
/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
    0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +2.8 TB     disk2
                                  Logical Volume on disk0s2, disk1s2
                                  03BC8817-F05E-4FC3-9A5C-50130CDAB3AB
                                  Unencrypted Fusion Drive
```

**diskutil cs list**

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group DFD31523-36BE-47AB-A666-54B64038E46B
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         2793817645056 B (2.8 TB)
    Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume FEC1934B-53F8-49A1-ABE6-5155689D9A68
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     120988852224 B (121.0 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 4F985EA2-E22B-451F-BEB3-E5EF76D14A59
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     2672828792832 B (2.7 TB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 27D90160-503D-48B7-B434-798CEE738260
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 03BC8817-F05E-4FC3-9A5C-50130CDAB3AB
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          2787630755840 B (2.8 TB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
            LVG Type:              Fusion, Sparse
```

Is there another way to expand the partition? Maybe a third party software solution?

Comment: I added the details requested. I am trying to enlarge "Data".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good message: you can resize both partitions with on-board tools. The bad message: you can't change the start block of a partition to a lower block number (i.e expand *Data* to lower block numbers). The partition *Data* has to be deleted first.

**Preparation:**

- Backup your Mac
- Safe all files and folders in *Data* to an external drive
- If you don't have an external drive you can also save the files to *Macintosh HD* – if it contains enough free space for all files (~223 GB) and the expansion size of *Data*. Example: If you want to expand *Data* by 673 GB (to 1000 GB!) you need at least 926 GB (223 GB + 673 GB + ~30 GB some free space for the system) free space on *Macintosh HD*.
- Detach any external drive (especially your external Time Machine backup drive)
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup. Booting to Recovery Mode is not conducive because the Recovery HD will be moved in one of the steps below. And you can't move a partition used as a boot volume.

  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot into a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an Apple/Akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

  Alternatively you may start from a bootable installer thumb drive (preferably Yosemite or El Capitan) or a thumb drive containing a full system (preferably Yosemite or El Capitan). If you boot to a full system and login as admin you have to prepend `sudo` to execute special commands like `gpt ...`!

**Remove the partition *Data* and shrink the  CoreStorage Volume Group**

- Booted to Internet Recovery Mode open Utilities → Terminal in the menubar and enter:  `diskutil list` to get the disk identifiers and `diskutil cs list` to get a CoreStorage listing. Below I assume that your main disks have the disk identifiers disk0 (usually the SSD)/disk1(usually the HDD) and the CoreStorage Logical Volume disk2.
- First you have to remove the *Data* partition:

  ```
  gpt -r show /dev/disk1 #to get an overview
  ```

  To remove a partition with `gpt` the disks (and all related disks like the inherent CoreStorage volume) have to be unmounted - first the CoreStorage Logical Volume and then the physical disks (SSD and HDD):

  ```
  diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
  diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk1
  diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0
  gpt remove -i 4 /dev/disk1 #remove the *Data* partition
  ```
- Then you have to resize the Logical Volume Group:

  ```
  diskutil mount /dev/disk0s2 #mount the physical volume of the CoreStorage Logical Volume Group
  diskutil mount /dev/disk1s2 #mount the physical volume of the CoreStorage Logical Volume Group
  diskutil mount lvUUID #lvUUID: the logical volume UUID - in your case 03BC8817-F05E-4FC3-9A5C-50130CDAB3AB
  diskutil cs resizeStack lvUUID size
  ```

  in your case (assuming you want to "resize" *Data* to 1000 GB (3121 GB-1000=2121 GB):

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack 03BC8817-F05E-4FC3-9A5C-50130CDAB3AB 2121g
  ```

  Your Recovery HD should be moved automatically - regardless of whether shrinking or expanding the CS volume - to the very end of it.
- Enter the following to get the new partition scheme:

  ```
  gpt -r -vv show /dev/disk1
  ```
- To add a partition with `gpt` the disks (and all related disks like the inherent CoreStorage volume) has to be unmounted

  ```
  diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2 #use the diskidentifier of the CS logical volume
  diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk1 #use the diskidentifier of the HDD
  diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0 #use the diskidentifier of the SSD
  ```
- Enter

  ```
  gpt add -b StartBlock -s NumberOfBlocks -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk1
  ```

  to create a new HFSJ+ partition on disk1. *StartBlock* is the number of the first block in the unallocated space and *NumberOfBlocks* is the number of free blocks or smaller. *NumberOfBlocks* has to be equally divisible through 8!

  ***Example:***

  if the result of `gpt -r -vv show /dev/disk1` is

  ```
  gpt show: /dev/disk1: mediasize=68719476736; sectorsize=512; blocks=134217728
  gpt show: /dev/disk1: PMBR at sector 0
  gpt show: /dev/disk1: Pri GPT at sector 1
  gpt show: /dev/disk1: Sec GPT at sector 134217727
        start       size  index  contents
            0          1         PMBR
            1          1         Pri GPT header
            2         32         Pri GPT table
           34          6         
           40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
       409640  104974016      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
    105383656    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
    106653192   27564503      
    134217695         32         Sec GPT table
    134217727          1         Sec GPT header
  ```

  then *StartBlock* would be 106653192 and the *NumberOfBlocks*  (27564503/8=3445562,875 -> 3445562*8) 27564496

  The resulting gpt command to create a new JHFS+ partition occupying all available free space would be:

  ```
  gpt add -b 106653192 -s 27564496 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk1
  ```
- Enter `exit` and quit *Terminal*
- Open *Disk Utility* and erase/initialize the newly created volume
- Check the main volume *Macintosh HD* for errors
- Quit *Disk Utility* and reboot to your main volume

Comment: `gpt remove -i 4 /dev/disk1 #remove the *Data* partition` returns the error `Resource is busy`.

Comment: I tried that but I still get the error

Comment: @RHPT Have you booted your mac to Internet recovery mode?

Comment: Yes, I did that when I attempted it the first time.

Comment: @RHPT First time? Second time? The message `Resource is busy` only occurs if one of the partitions of disk1 is mounted/in use - either directly because partition disk1sx is mounted to /Volumes/MountName or indirectly because files are in use (e.g booting to Recovery HD (disk1s3) or the CoreStorage Logical Volume is mounted).

Comment: I tried again, and got it working this time. I think I was using the wrong disk id. Thanks for your help!